# Why is appfuse not sending emails? (SMTPSendFailedException)

Tags: java, smtp, appfuse

I used the [appfuse quickstart](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart#AppFuseQuickStart-create) to create a basic Spring MVC project.

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-spring-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=3.0.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse
```

I signed up at https://mailtrap.io (a fake smtp service). I edited the `mail.properties` file with the mailtrap credentials:

```
mail.default.from=AppFuse <appfuse@raibledesigns.com>
mail.host=mailtrap.io
mail.username=199******d30ac
mail.password=ca8******aae39
```

I launched the app and tried to register a new user, but I got:

```
ERROR [qtp8455718-31] MailEngine.send(78) | Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required
```

I double checked the credentials and I'm sure they are correct.

I googled and found the [source code for MailEngine](http://raibledesigns.com/downloads/appfuse/api/org/appfuse/service/MailEngine.java.html), it looks like a wrapper around `org.springframework.mail.MailSender`.

I'm a bit dissapointed, I thought appfuse was supposed to work out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've properly edited (see comments in bold) the following section in applicationContext-service.xml file as too:

> <bean id="mailSender"
>   class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
>           <property name="host" value="${mail.host}"/>
>           <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
>           **<!-- Uncomment if you need to authenticate with your SMTP Server -->**
>           **<!--property name="username" value="${mail.username}"/>
>
>           <property name="password" value="${mail.password}"/>
>
>           <property name="javaMailProperties">
>
>               <value>
>
>                mail.smtp.auth=true
>
>               </value>
>
>            </property-->**
>   </bean>

hope that helps.

Comment: Note: applicationContext-service.xml can be generated with "mvn appfuse:full-source", see http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/Email-Gmail-troubles-td4656734.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thread on the mailing list that seems similar:

http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/SMTP-Authentication-with-Struts-2-App-td560701.html